XFY-1 Pogo Contrarotating props alternative?
The Convair XFY-1 Pogo was a tail-sitter VTOL aircraft that used contrarotating props. I believe it was to counter the torque that would be produced if a single prop was used. Why couldn't the Pogo use the control surfaces on its tail to counter the torque instead of using contrarotating props? In other words, if the Pogo had been designed with a single prop, would it be possible for it to counter the torque using the control surfaces in the prop-wash (by creating a rolling moment opposite to the torque)? Could this be applied to a smaller aircraft such as the SkyTote UAV?


if the Pogo had been designed with a single prop, would it be possible for it to counter the torque using the control surfaces in the prop-wash?

Using the control surfaces blown upon by the propwash was the way to control it during takeoff and landing. With some bigger and skewed control surface it might have been possible to control it and to (partially) offset the torque even if it were built with one propeller only.
Anyway, why make things even more complicated than what they already were? A contra-rotating configuration made the slipstream (more or less) axisymmetric, disposed of any anti-torque mechanism and doubled the thrust without increasing the radius of the propeller.

When you advance the throttle, the torque (nearly) instantly increases.  However, the propwash does not immediately increase.  So your control authority using aerodynamic surfaces to counter the torque lags substantially.  When you are at idle, you have very little control authority -- and the torque is reacted by the landing gear contact with the ground.  This would lead to a highly nonlinear control system.  By using counter-rotating props, the torque self-cancels without any fancy control system or nonlinear effect.  It is a much simpler solution.

Yes, increasing the throttle gradually would have been necessary to give time to the propwash to reach the control surfaces and give them the possibility to generate enough lift. For sure at landing this is actually how it was controlled despite the delay and at the end it might have been possible also with only one propeller but, as said, why make things complicated?

There is a difference between controlling the vehicle this way -- when the torque is already cancelled vs. cancelling the torques and providing control.  I'm not disagreeing that propwash was use for control.  It certainly was.  However, I believe it would be implausible to use propwash exclusively to counter the torque of this vehicle.

Maybe with some bigger and skewed control surfaces might have been possible to partially cancel the torque out... But again, it might have been possible but definitely nonsense

@sophit, Please refer to the SkyTote UAV (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroVironment_SkyTote ), which looks like a mini version of the Pogo (without the delta wing). In this case, wouldn't it be less complicated (mechanically) and weigh less if a single propeller was used with bigger control surfaces? Because I imagine the contra-rotating props would be more complicated, compared to using the servos which would be needed anyway. Also, can the propwash be utilized better by using control canards? I am trying to design such a UAV, so thank you for your advice!

The contra-rotating propeller needs only a couple of ball bearings and cogwheels. The bigger surface needed to counteract the torque would be heavier and generate additional drag. The anti-torque control would also be quite "nervous". A contra-rotating propeller is definitely the way to go.
